# Declare member variable and initialize without repeating type

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

In C# I can do this in a method:

```
var Content = new Dictionary<string, System.Text.StringBuilder>();
```

and in VB.Net I can do this in a method:

```
Dim Content = new Dictionary(of string, System.Text.StringBuilder)
```

However in VB I can also do this outside of a method when defining a field/member variable (note, in this case, VB is not inferring the type, it's getting it explicitly, this was in VB.Net prior to 'option infer'):

```
Dim Content AS new Dictionary(of string, System.Text.StringBuilder)
```

In C# it seems like I have to do it like this:

```
Dictionary<string, System.Text.StringBuilder> Content = new Dictionary<string, System.Text.StringBuilder>();
```

Notice I am having to repeat the type twice.

This is a simple example, for more complex cases it does get at least a bit annoying.

I can't believe something is more compact in VB; am I missing something here? How to I declare a member variable and initialize without repeating the type?

#### edit

From the Eric Lippert document mentioned in comments by Ron: "... *If our goal is to remove the redundancy, I would therefore prefer to remove it the other way. Make this legal: private static readonly Dictionary niceNames =   new()...  That is, state the type unambiguously in the declaration and then have the "new" operator be smart about figuring out what type it is constructing based on what type it is being assigned to* ..."
So there is an idea floated by Eric himself about how it could be done - really this is all that VB does.  (very good catch on finding that document, by the way Ron)

Comment: var Content = new Dictionary<string, System.Text.StringBuilder>

Comment: @NoAlias - that only works in a method. What to do for Fields / Member-variables of the class itself?

Comment: [Eric Lippert: Why no var on fields?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/01/26/why-no-var-on-fields/)

Comment: You don't have a shoter way in C#. Only inside methods you could use `var` like NoAlias said. Just accept it.

Comment: @Ron Beyer - that article makes complete sense. It is also why VB.Net doesn't allow Dim id = _type inferable expr_ (which is eq to c# var id = _type inferable expr_). But vb's Dim id __AS__ _type inferable expr_ doesn't do all the smarts eric is talking about. It just takes the type returned by the contructor, an easy thing to figure out. (Dim .. AS .. doesn't allow anything fancier e.g., any old expression like inference, but rather just a constructor)

Comment: @H.Pauwelyn ... I will probably have to accept it, and that's OK. Really it's a little deal, I'm not volunteering to change it :-)

Comment: @FastAl In the edge case you are talking about, you are right, it isn't any kind of complicated matter. But there are other cases that it wouldn't work, like a `var` referencing a `var` of another class, and on and on. Since they can't resolve *every* case, they don't allow *any* case.

Comment: Sadly we have new() but no new[] - when declaring a Class Member that contains an Array, you have to be redundant - and those can be really long, like, public static Expression<Func<SkaterItemViewModel, string>>[] Properties = new Expression<Func<SkaterItemViewModel, string>>[]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And now, in C# 9.0, we have target-typed `new` expressions to implement what @EricLippert suggested.

```
Dictionary<string, System.Text.StringBuilder> Content = new();
```

Comment: YES!! such a little thing, it would seem. But I love it so much :-)

Comment: @FastAl The more I think about it, the more I wish they had gone the other way. Or did both. The language forces you to be inconsistent because `var` is required when working with LINQ and anonymous types, but not allowed when doing fields (which also means you can't create a field that refers to an anonymous type).

Answer (score 1):

You can't without repeating the type, but you could use an alias (created with a "using" statement) if the type is complex.

Comment: That's a start, I hadn't thought of that.